# How can I make button appears above pushpin when pushpin is clicked in bing maps?

Tags: windows-phone-7, button, bing-maps, pushpin

It should be look like this. When pushpin is clicked.

[image]

This is my XAML.

```
<my:Pushpin Name="pin1" Location="60.285323,24.943501" Template="{StaticResource normalPushPin}" MouseLeftButtonUp="Location1_Popup"/>
```

This my Location1_Popup method. I don't know what to write.

```
private void Location1_Popup(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Location1 has been clicked");
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What I'm supposed to write in the Location1_Popup method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make now your popup visible in the MouseDown Event.

For examples, please have a look the sourcecode.

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/upload/articles/WPPinPopup-Alternatives.zip

[image]

```
private void Location1_Popup(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        BlackRegionWithContent.Visible = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```